# settings is not opening in windows 10 after update?

Tags: windows-10

#### settings is not opening in windows 10 after updating window 10 2004.

I updated my window 10 operating system but after update settings and it's related app is not opening.

Answer (score 1):

### FIX: Settings App Not Working In Windows 10

1. Open administrative Windows PowerShell. For this, simply right click Start Button or press W8K + X keys and select Windows PowerShell (Admin). You can also search for Windows PowerShell using Cortana and right click the same from results and select Run as administrator.

2. Next, in the PowerShell window, type/paste following cmdlet and press Enter key.

   Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name windows.immersivecontrolpanel | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml” -Verbose}

3.Let the command complete. Close Windows PowerShell and reboot the machine. After restarting your system, see if you can launch the Settings app now.

hope this method is work properly. If this method is not working please comment either you get proper solution then my request to you please submit your answer it might be help to other people who facing this issue.